# SocketAsyncEventArgs - how to detect socket operation in progress & terminate?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am receiving this error sometimes:

> An asynchronous socket operation is already in progress using this SocketAsyncEventArgs instance.

...when I try to call `SocketServiceEventArgs.SetBuffer()`

I realise this is because an instance can only perform one operation and it must be in use. However I am calling it again because after a previous timeout from the client side, I wish to attempt to resend the request. I don't wish to close this socket and use a new one because then the connection will be broken with the client.

However, what I need to do is check whether another operation is already in progress before doing this, and if so, terminate it, so that I can send again.

The code I am using to send is

`saeaCommunicationObject.AcceptSocket.SendAsync(saeaCommunicationObject)`

but what's more likely to be in progress is the Receive which is

`saeaCommunicationObject.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(saeaCommunicationObject))`

(`saeaCommunicationObject` is a `SocketAsyncEventArgs`).

In research, I have come across

`AcceptSocket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)`

but I'm not sure if this is correct, and also I have no idea where to get asyncResult (so if this is correct, my question is, where is this supposed to come from?)

So what can I do to either check if it's in progress (and if so, terminate it)?

**Edit**

One place I looked suggested (but did not recommend) the use of `CancelIoEx()` using P/Invoke - however I couldn't get this to work and there is very little documentation on this.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool CancelIoEx(IntPtr hFile);

private void CancelReceive() {
   bool result = CancelIoEx(saeaCommunicationObject.AcceptSocket.Handle)
   // etc.
}
```

I get `result` = `false`. I've also tried `CancelIo()` and while I get `result` = `true`, the same exception is thrown when I try to call the `SetBuffer()`.

**TL;DR**

Once `ReceiveAsync()` is called and so now the socket is waiting on input in order to fire the `Completed` event, how do I cancel this request?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

> Returns true if the I/O operation is pending. The SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed event on the e parameter will be raised upon completion of the operation.
>   Returns false if the I/O operation completed synchronously. In this case, The SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed event on the e parameter will not be raised and the e object passed as a parameter may be examined immediately after the method call returns to retrieve the result of the operation.

So, you should check the return value of the `ReceiveAsync` call. If its `true` subscribe to the `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed` event. If it's false then check the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` immediately to verify the result.

Comment: Thanks, but if it's pending (which I assume means it's waiting for input from the client), I want to cancel it. And also, if it's not pending, I don't want to make it pending.

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit the comment, but: I want to check has `ReceiveAsync()` already been called. (i.e. it's already pending). If so, then cancel this. If I just call `ReceiveAsync()` again to do the check, then I get the same exception, but this time from this call (rather than the `SetBuffer()`).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer to the specific question, but my current workaround is to check the `AcceptSocket.BytesAvailable` value and wait for it to be > 0 before calling `ReceiveAsync()`. That way it can be interrupted if I need to call `SendAsync()` first.

I think that this will be a little less efficient and I'm not sure how scaleable it will be, considering there could be up to 50 clients connecting at the same time - but it seems to be getting me over this hump for now.